# AWS Elastic Beanstalk log time deploy Python Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I use AWS Elastic Beanstalk and have an issue when trying deploy new feature code in Python Django. It takes so much time - about 30min. I don't know why and I wish have any ideal how to check it.

My question is: How to log time deploy in AWS Elastic Beanstalk? Step by step running deploy in AWS to find what takes time to deploy the server.

Comment: You can get all logs file from EC2 instance via elastic beanstalk console.

Comment: i read log in ec2 instance but dont know what step take time deploy, do you have any ideal to check it or log it?

Comment: Try to get log files via aws EB console. Zip file will contain all of them.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html